# Downloading a file using WebClient after logging into a website using WebBrowser

Tags: c#, browser, download, webclient

I used the WebBrowser class to sign into a website and get a url for a download I want.  I can't get the download via WebBrowser because I can't programmatically communicate with the download dialog box.

Based on my research it appears that I have to use WebClient to handle my download.  How can I pass the "authenicated" cookies from WebBrowser to WebClient and get my download without fussing with a dialog box?

Answer (score 0):

You can grab the WebBrowser's credentials using the InternetGetCookieEx API. You can then attach a cookie collection to the HTTPWebRequest and populate it using the credentials from the WebBrowser control.

Having said that, what do you mean when you say "can't programmatically communicate with the download dialog box"?  What sort of communication were you hoping for?

Comment: In WebBrowser, once I click the download link, I get a file dialog box (open, save, cancel) and can't make a selection without physically using my mouse or keyboard (I want to do this with just the script).

Comment: There is no way to automate that dialog box that pops up in the window of your WebBrowser control. You need to figure out what the URL of the file will be and use a HTTPWebRequest, with cookies attached as EricLaw describes, to request that URL and save it to disk yourself in your C# program